# How to prove inequality $\;\frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}}\le2\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;x,y\ge 1\;$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have this great problem: to prove

$$\frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}}\le 2\;,\;\;\forall\;x,y\ge1\;?$$

Multiplicate by conjugated I get left side as

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{y^2+y}}{x-y}\le 2$$

but I can't get any more, and I can't use derivatives or multiple limits since we didn't study these yet.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @peterwhy, I wrote again correctly.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+x}>x$, $\sqrt{y^2+y}>y$, so your expression is $<\frac{x+y+1}{x+y}=1+\frac{1}{x+y}\leq\frac32<2$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I feel as dumb as old shoe. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $x,y\ge 1$.

$\therefore x<\sqrt{x^2+x}$ and $y<\sqrt{y^2+y}$ $\implies$ $x+y<\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}$

$$\frac{x+y+1}{x+y}>\frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}} $$ and 
$\frac{x+y+1}{x+y}=1+\frac{1}{x+y}\le \frac{3}{2}$, because $x+y\ge2$

> $$\therefore \frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}} <2 $$

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was essentially the same as yours and you were faster than me :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the denominator of the LHS is positive you are allowed to cross multiply. So it can be simplified as follows:-$$\begin{align}&(x+y+1)^2\le 4\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}\right)^2\\&=>x^2+y^2+2xy+2x+2y+1\le 4x^2+4y^2+4x+4y+8\sqrt{(x^2+x)(y^2+y)}\\&=>2x^2+2y^2+(x-y)^2+2x+2y+8\sqrt{(x^2+x)(y^2+y)}-1\ge 0\end{align}$$ This is obviously true because $2(x+y)-1\ge 3$ as $x,y\ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\ge0$, $\sqrt{x^2+x}\ge x$, and since $x\ge1$, $\sqrt{x^2+x}\ge \sqrt2$. Thus,
$$
\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}}\le1
$$
and
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}}\le\frac1{2\sqrt2}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}}\le1+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\lt2
$$